# Как использовать сторонние шрифты в PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, шрифты, pysimplegui

Нигде не нашёл: есть ли возможность использования пользовательских шрифтов в PySimpleGui?

Comment: Думаю это как-то возможно. Поищите в коде класс в котором надо изменить шрифт и посмотрите какие переменные он может принимать. К сожалению больше никак это не выяснить, т.к.почти  нету по нему доков или инфы

Comment: И языки не нашел, как поменять на кнопку submit().

Answer (score 0):

**Для вывода текста, можно сделать таким способом**

```
sg.Text(username,font=("Bahnschrift Light",8))
```